# Check Status of replicas of StatefulState using io.fabric8.kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I am terminating pods in a stateful state using `io.fabric8.kubernetes` client as

```
client
        .inNamespace(namespace)
        .pods()
        .withLabel("xx", "xxx")
        .delete()
```

### How can check if the StatefulSet is recovered back ?

What I am trying :

```
StatefulSet statefulSet = client
            .pods()
            .inNamespace("namespace-xxx")
            .statefulSets()
            .inNamespace(namespace)
            .withName("statefulset-name")
            .get();

StatefulSetStatus status = statefulSet.getStatus();
StatefulSetSpec spec = statefulSet.getSpec();
```

and then checking the condition

```
spec.getReplicas.intValue != status.getReadyReplicas.intValue
```

However this condition seems to be meeting even when the pods are not Ready!

Comment: Client api is asynchronous in nature, you should check whether it was even ready or not after change using `isReady()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone said in the comments, the client API is asynchronous by nature. This means that you should think differently from the procedural way to check the status of an action. As you can see from the documentation https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client#following-events the client allows you to define a watcher, where you can specify in the anonymous class all the actions to be performed when the desired event/status happens.